# Implicit equation between rational function and its derivative

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be a complex rational function in one variable. How does one find a complex polynomial $P$ in two variables such that $P(f,f^\prime)=0$?

EDIT: as the answers explained there is a standard procedure using resultant to obtain $P$. see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Algebraic_geometry . 
However this process is computationally very heavy. I was wondering if in the case when $g=f^\prime$ we may know $P$ more explicitly, if we had some other, more efficient way to compute it.

Comment: How do you know that such a polynomial exists?

Comment: @Igor:  The curve $(x,y) = (f(t),f'(t))$ is a rational curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and hence is the zero locus of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: @RobertBryant I think you have just answered the OP's question...

Comment: @IgorRivin:  Actually, the question is 'How do you find...?", which I interpreted to mean, "What is an efficient method of finding $P$?".  That's not so clear.  Although a brute force method would clearly work, there might be something quicker than the obvious brute force method.

Comment: @RobertBryant I am not sure if by "brute force method" you mean the one in my answer, but in this case this will be fairly efficient, methinks.

Comment: @IgorRivin:  Yes, that is one of the two methods I had in mind. (The other was to solve a system of linear equations that would give the coefficients of the polynomial $P$.)  What's not clear to me is whether there is a more efficient algorithm in the special case of $(f,f')$ (rather than for the general rational curve).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, comments. My question was if the process simplifies in the case of the derivative.

Comment: What must be relevant is that when $f$ is a polynomial, the resultant of $f$ and $f'$ is the discriminant of $f$...

Comment: Yes, when $f$ is a polynomial the discriminant should be the constant term of $P$.

Answer (score 3):

The magic word is "implicitization". Consider the curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by $C = (f(t), f^\prime(t)).$ (as pointed out by Robert Bryant in the comments). Now, we would like to find the equation satisfied by the curve. This can be done for any pair of rational functions (not just $f, f^\prime$). Namely, we write down the pair of equations:

$$x = \frac{p(t)}{q(t)} \Leftrightarrow x q(t) = p(t)$$
$$y = \frac{r(t)}{s(t)} \Leftrightarrow y s(t) = r(t).$$

We can now eliminate $t$ from these equations, but thinking of both of them as being defined over $\mathbb{C}[x, y],$ and setting the [Sylvester matrix determinant resultant](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sylvester_matrix) to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I meant to ask if this process yields something special in the case when the second function is the derivative of the first.

Answer (score 3):

As Igor noted, this is all quite standard, and I'm really not sure it belongs on MO, since I'm sure it would certainly receive a quick answer on MathSE. Anyway, in order to compute an equation for the image of the implicit curve $\bigl(f(t),g(t)\bigr)$, where $f(t)=f_1(t)/f_2(t)$ and $g(t)=g_1(t)/g_2(t)$ are rational functions, compute the $t$-resultant
$$
\text{Resultant}_t\bigl( f_2(t)X-f_1(t), g_2(t)Y-g_1(t) \bigr).
$$
More generally, this sort of question in answered by elimination theory, and as a practical matter, one uses Grobner bases to compute such quantities.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I meant to ask if this process yields something recognizable when $g=f'$. Computationally this resultant could be terribly big, and maybe when $g=f'$ there is some more computable formula for $P$.

Comment: @Guest Seems unlikely that $g=f'$ yields anything particularly nice. If you take $f$ a generic quadratic or cubic, the resultant of $f-X$ and $f'-Y$ doesn't appear to have any nice shape.

Comment: Well, for polynomials, when you do the elimination, the constant term of the resulting equation in $x, y$ is the discriminant, so it *is* an interesting question of: what is the meaning of the other terms.

Comment: @IgorRivin But if you use $f$ and $g$, then the constant term is the resultant of $f$ and $g$, as is clear by plugging in $X=Y=0$. The other coefficients are polynomials that depend on the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ in some fashion, but it's not clear to me what "meaning" can be assigned to them. Maybe some sort of 2nd order information about common roots of $f$ and $g$. In any case, I don't see any reason why there would be some special "meaning" when $g=f'$ that isn't also interesting for general $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you say, though, for arbitrary $f, g$ the constant term is, arguably, less studied than the discriminant...